# Android 2.3.1 Camera takePicture() Multiple images with one button click

Tags: android, android-camera

Greetings. I am new to Android and haven't touched Java in a long time.

I'm working on an app specifically for the Nexus S with Android 2.3.1. I would like the app to take several photos quickly with little user input. At the moment I would like to be able to get 10 images from the camera as quickly as possible. In my code I have takePicture() being started like so:

```
takepicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // created button from main.xml
takepicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ // creating useful button
    public void onClick(View view){
        mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback,mPictureCallback,mjpeg); // when clicked take picture
        }
});
```

This works for one image per click which is saved using

```
PictureCallback mjpeg = new PictureCallback() { // for compressed picture data
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[],data, Camera c { /*Saving image to internal sd card*/ }
```

I tried putting *takePicture()* in a for loop but that didn't work. Any suggestions? Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably trying to take the second picture while taking the first one, and dismissing it. Wait a second or so between each takePicture() call. Or, much better, use the pictureCallback to fire the second takePicture()

Comment: Won't takePicture() in pictureCallback create a inf loop? How would I break out of that?

Comment: You can use a static counter to limit the number of calls. It would be also useful for the file numbering of the sequential photos

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow morning. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hey, finally had a chance to try this out. It worked! I added an "if counter is less than ten" statement and executed mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback,mPictureCallback,mjpeg); Thanks!