# Java: taking average of 16 image byte arrays in Android

Tags: java, android

my android app is taking several images in a row. Every time I take a picture using takePicture() I convert the byte array into a PNG using BitmapFactory. My final goal is to get the average of 16 images. To speed up the process I was thinking of averaging the byte arrays before creating a PNG instead of creating 16 images and then trying to average them. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Simply, I want to do something like this:

```
imgByteArray1 = [1,2,3,4]
imgByteArray2 = [4,3,2,1]

totalImgByteArray = imgByteArray1 + imgByteArray2
//totalImgByteArray will equal [5,5,5,5]
aveImgByteArray = totalImgByteArray / 2
//aveImgByteArray will equal [2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5]
```

Then from aveImgByteArray I can create a PNG file.

I'm using the same code as in [Android 2.3.1 Camera takePicture() Multiple images with one button click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545952/654781) to capture the images.
First I'm collecting the byte arrays into one byte array:

```
for(int i=0; i < data.length ; i++)
    totalImgData[i] = (byte) (totalImgData[i] + data[i]);
```

Then I'm averaging across the array after I've collected for 16 images:

```
for (int j=0; j < totalImgData.length; j++)
    aveImgData[j] = (byte) (totalImgData[j] / 16);
```

This doesn't work... Sorry I'm a bit new to Android with Java.

Comment: I've updated the post with what I'm trying now.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you take a picture you get a `byte[]` in the callback with the data. Just keep track of that information, ex.

```
long totalBytes = 0;
int count = 0;

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data ...)
{
    ....
    totalBytes += data.length;
    count++;
}
```

Then when you are done you can calculate the avg:

```
//This isn't the best example (all the type casts), but it gives you the idea
long avg = (long) Math.ceil((double) totalBytes / (double) count);
```

I'm not sure what the point is though --- you probably don't want to store 16 images in memory at the same time. When you get the `byte[]` back from Android, you have the raw image data which could be quite large. Storing 16 of those things will definitely put a major drain on your app (assuming it doesn't crash.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. For my project I need to eliminate as much noise from the images as possible. Averaging should cure that a little. The images are 480x360. I don't think that will fill up the memory to the point of causing problems. I'll try it out. Do I have to keep all 16 arrays in memory? I just add to totalBytes. That won't get bigger memory-wise right? Just the values will increase. I am I not understanding how totalBytes += data.length works?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by eliminating noise from the image, if you need to manipulate the image, then you need to store the bytes because `onPictureTaken` is the last stop before the array is marked for garbage collection. All `totalBytes += data.length` does is keep a sum of the # bytes. It is equivalent to `totalBytes = data.length + totalBytes`