# android camera click continous shots

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am trying to make camera application which takes 3 continuous shots.

i have tried to call "takePicture" several times by putting it in a loop.

but no success.

please help on this matter.

a little help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's called callback because you are not supposed to call it, but have it called. Call "takePicture".

Comment: sorry question needs some corrections.

Answer (score 3):

You never should call `PictureCallback.onPictureTaken()` from your code; this callback receives data from the system when it is ready, as response to `Camera.takePicture()`.

The latter call will only succeed if the camera is opened and preview is started. Therefore, simply calling `Camera.takePicture()` in a loop will not work (see e.g. [Android 2.3.1 Camera takePicture() Multiple images with one button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545952/android-2-3-1-camera-takepicture-multiple-images-with-one-button-click)). The correct way to handle this is to keep a counter of shots processed in your `onPictureTaken()`, and if it is less than 3, then restart camera preview and issue (synchroneously) another `Camera.takePicture()`. After this, `onPictureTaken()` should `return`, to allow processing of the next captured frame.

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this when doing a PhotoBurst. It is also handling the FRameLayout holding the preview to start the PhotoBurst:

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {

            Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
            param.setPictureSize(640, 480);
            camera.setParameters(param);

             // Or write to sdcard
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/foto%d.jpg",
                    System.currentTimeMillis()));

            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,                           
                     Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

            Log.i(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpg");
        try {
            stillCount++;
            camera.startPreview();
            if (stillCount < 10) {
                preview.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                        jpegCallback);
                if (stillCount == 9) {
                    frameLayout.setClickable(true);
                }
            } else {
                stillCount = 0;
                takePictureButton.setEnabled(true);
                frameLayout.setClickable(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting preview: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

i was calling `mCamera.startPreview();` out of my loop.

preview is must to take shots, and not including `mCamera.startPreview();` was blocking my execution.