# how to measure the time it takes the android camera to capture a single frame at real-time?

Tags: android, performance, real-time, android-camera

I'm doing some performance testing of real-time possibilities on Android, because I need to show if acquiring a frame using OpenCV Java methods are more efficient and faster than the android SDK methods. So I want to know (if possible) as you can measure the exact time it takes the camera android sensor taking a single frame?

The initial code I had was just getting the time before and after the time takePicture after, subtract and save that time in an array then make averages, etc. But my code did not work because it was inside a while loop.

My interest is not to show the images in preview, my interest is to show the time it takes the sensor to acquire a frame or capture. I know that the frame is acquired in raw form and then the Android SDK provides the tools to transform it into a jpeg image but that does not interest me.

p.d. I do the same tests using Java methods and then the methods of C. Something like Android-OpenCV Java methods versus Android SDK for android Java methods. And the same in C, C functions of OpenCV for Android versus native C functions in android.

The refference links are:
[Capturing Multiple Photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336890/capturing-multiple-photos)

But I'm not sure.

Thanks all