# Taking multiple photos via Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I would like to take multiple photos via Intent. I know how to make intent for taking just one image, but what if I would like to take e.g. 10 photos?

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  }
}
```

Trivial solution is to  make another intent after result but I think there must be better solution, isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something by using some trick, one of the question asked on the stackoverflow will help you, [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5338881/2915785) 
second check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649144/2915785) 
these two links will surely help you.
the second link recomend this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
    MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question, do you know, how can I get taken images?

Comment: you have to keep a uri where the taken picture saves...
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String fileName = TravellerUtils.generateUniqueID()
                + IMAGE_FILE_EXT;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                TravellerConstants.IMAGE_PATH + fileName);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
dont know exact solution but you can get idea now

Comment: why you reomved Question Selection? I have answered what you asked?

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake :) Thank you so much. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to use `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` in order to disable selecting image from the phone gallery.

In order to achieve "similar" behaviour with taking several pictures I was starting next camera intent directly from `onActivityResult` while processing recently taken photo in background.

Code looks like this:

```
...
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            return
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Timber.d("Taking image was cancelled")
            return
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            lastTakenPhotoData?.let {
                handlePhotoTaken(it)
                startCameraIntent()
            }
        }
    }
...

    private fun handlePhotoTaken(...) {
        disposable.add(
            Single.fromCallable { compressPhotoTaken(data) }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe { _ ->
                        //update UI with processed photo
                    }
        )
    }
...
    private fun compressTakenPhoto(...) {
        //rotate, compress, save taken photo to the local file if needed
        //this part was taking quite a lot of time, so it is better to do it in background
    }
```